# Hibernate JPA: Named Query Select statement is deleting and adding rows to mapping table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an entity called SecurityUser that is mapped to another entity SecurityRole via a many-to-many mapping table called SECURITY_USER_ROLE.

SecurityUser entity:

```
@Entity
@Named("securityUser")
@Table(name = "SECURITY_USER")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
            name = SecurityUser.GET_ALL_USERS_WITH_ROLES,
            query = "select u from SecurityUser u join fetch u.securityRoles join fetch u.userLanguage")})

public class SecurityUser extends AuditEntity implements Serializable {

public static final String GET_ALL_USERS_WITH_ROLES = "getAllUsersWithRoles";

@Id
@Column(name = "USER_LOGIN")
private String userLogin;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userLogin")
private Set<UserLastSelection> userLastSelections = new HashSet<UserLastSelection>(0);

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = SecurityRole.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "SECURITY_USER_ROLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_LOGIN"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"))
private List<SecurityRole> securityRoles;


@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_LOGIN")
private UserLanguage userLanguage;
```

SecurityRole entity:

```
@Entity
@Named("securityRole")
@Table(name = "SECURITY_ROLE")

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ROLE_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SECURITY_ROLE_ID_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "ROLE_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 12)
private Long id;

@Length(max = 50)
@Column(name = "ROLE_NAME")
private String roleName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "securityRole", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
private List<SecurityRolePermission> securityRolePermission;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "securityRole", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
private List<SecurityRoleLookup> securityRoleLookups;
```

SecurityUserRole entity:

```
@Entity
@Named("securityUserRole")
@Table(name = "SECURITY_USER_ROLE")
public class SecurityUserRole extends AuditEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UserRoleIdSeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "UserRoleIdSeq", sequenceName = "SECURITY_USER_ROLE_ID_SEQ")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_LOGIN")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
private SecurityUser user;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
private SecurityRole securityRole;

@Column(name = "ROLE_STATUS")
private String roleStatus;
```

I'd like to fetch the securityUsers with the named query `GET_ALL_USERS_WITH_ROLES`. However, when I use my named query to fetch the list of SecurityUsers, at the end of the transaction Hibernate runs a delete statement on a mapping table on a specific user and then adds back in the rows that it originally deleted.

Method using the named query:

```
public List<Object[]> fetchUsers() {
    List<SecurityUser> securityUsers = securityUserDAO.fetchAllSecurityUsersWithRoles();
    List<Object[]> userArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    return userArrayList;
}
```

SecurityUserDAO:

```
public class SecurityUserDAO extends BaseDAO {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<SecurityUser> fetchAllSecurityUsersWithRoles() {
    List<SecurityUser> securityUsers = entityManager.createNamedQuery(SecurityUser.GET_ALL_USERS_WITH_ROLES)
            .getResultList();

    return securityUsers;
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
     Hibernate: 
     delete 
     from
         SECURITY_USER_ROLE 
     where
         USER_LOGIN=?

 MSG=binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - user_A

 Hibernate: 
     insert 
     into
         SECURITY_USER_ROLE
         (USER_LOGIN, ROLE_ID) 
     values
         (?, ?)

MSG=binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - user_A

MSG=binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 4

 Hibernate: 
     insert 
     into
         SECURITY_USER_ROLE
         (USER_LOGIN, ROLE_ID) 
     values
         (?, ?)

  MSG=binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - user_A

 MSG=binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 1570

 Hibernate: 
     insert 
     into
         SECURITY_USER_ROLE
         (USER_LOGIN, ROLE_ID) 
     values
         (?, ?)

MSG=binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - user_A

 MSG=binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 15

 Hibernate: 
     insert 
     into
         SECURITY_USER_ROLE
         (USER_LOGIN, ROLE_ID) 
     values
         (?, ?)

 MSG=binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - user_A

 MSG=binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 26

 Hibernate: 
     insert 
     into
         SECURITY_USER_ROLE
         (USER_LOGIN, ROLE_ID) 
     values
         (?, ?)

 MSG=binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - user_A

  MSG=binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 9

 Hibernate: 
     insert 
     into
         SECURITY_USER_ROLE
         (USER_LOGIN, ROLE_ID) 
     values
         (?, ?)

  MSG=binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - user_A

 MSG=binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 1546

 Hibernate: 
     insert 
     into
         SECURITY_USER_ROLE
         (USER_LOGIN, ROLE_ID) 
     values
         (?, ?)

  MSG=binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - user_A

 MSG=binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 1387

 Hibernate: 
     insert 
     into
         SECURITY_USER_ROLE
         (USER_LOGIN, ROLE_ID) 
     values
         (?, ?)

  MSG=binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - user_A

 MSG=binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 1280

11:56:48,783 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
11:56:48,784 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
11:56:48,786 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA_NAME"."SECURITY_USER_ROLE"."ROLE_STATUS")
```

Each of these user login/role id combinations that are being inserted existed in the mapping table `SECURITY_USER_ROLE` before the delete. user_A exists in the `SECURITY_USER` table and the role_ids exist in the `SECURITY_ROLE` table. The inserts failed because ROLE_STATUS is a non-nullable column on `SECURITY_USER_ROLE`. Even when I don't touch the list that I fetched, I still get these delete and insert statements. **Why would the Hibernate delete rows from my mapping table and then try to add them back in when I'm running a named query that is a select statement?**

I'm using JBoss EAP 6.1 and hibernate version 4.2.14.Final